# 5 repeats of a for loop multiplication

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a beginner at python, and have been given this task:
Write a program that lets a user input numbers and have them multiplied. The user can use the program 5 times, then it should stop. Use at least a for loop and a function.

I believe the code here will ask for the numbers, multiply and give the answer, but how do I get it to run 5 times then stop asking for more numbers?

```py
# get inputs
num1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))

# calculate product
product = 0
for i in range(1,num2+1):
    product=product+num1`  

# give answer
print("The Product of Number:", product)
```

Comment: `product=product+num1` is a bit of an oxymoron. You want a product but you're doing a sum instead!

Comment: add a big loop around it with a counter that goes from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I get it to run 5 times then stop asking for more numbers?

1. Get rid of the `for i in range(1,num2+1)` loop, since you don't need a loop in order to calculate the product of two numbers.
2. Add a `for i in range(5)` loop at the very top of your code, and then indent everything under it 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: Including code would be a better answer.

Comment: @jarmod: I think that in this specific case, he'd be better off practicing that himself. The question (and subsequently the answer) is extremely basic. There's not much added value in providing the full solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set limit of the repetition
lim = 5

while lim>0:
   # get inputs
   num1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
   num2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
   
   # give answer
   product = num1*num2
   print(f"The Product of Number {num1} and {num2} is ", product)
   lim = lim - 1
```

Basically while we haven't done 5 multiplications, the programm will ask the user to give it numbers to multiply. I used `f-string` formatting so you can use the number value inside your string your displaying. The syntax is simply `f"your string with value {the_value_you_want}"`